# Write an equation of a linear relation representing this scenario.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In water, the greater the depth, the higher the pressure. For every 10 m increase in depth, water pressure increases by about 100 kilopascals (kPa). At a depth of
40, the pressure is approximately 500 kPa.

a. State the independent and dependent variables in this scenario.

In this scenario pressure is the dependent variable and depth is the independent variable, because it stands alone and isn’t affected by any other variable. The pressure is the dependent variable because it depends on the depth, which is the independent variable.

b.   What is the rate of change in this relationship?

To find the rate of change I'm assuming I use Change in pressure / change in depth which is vertical change / horizontal change.

c. Write the equation of a linear relation representing the pressure, p, at a depth, d, under water.

I understand the form for a linear equation is y = mx + b, but I keep getting confused with this question. Originally i had y=dx+100, but i went on to the the rest of the questions to come to the quick realization that it does not work when you need to solve the pressure at a certain depth and a depth at a certain pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can find the rate of change by using the information telling us about the 10 m increase resulting in 100 kPa higher pressure. Then to find the linear function we plug in our rate of change (or slope) and the point we are given. I made a video explaining how this problem is done. Let me know if anything is unclear or if there is any other way I can help!

[Here is the video](http://youtu.be/i0bPFDKKHWY)

Comment: Thank you so much for the video, it was very informative! If the question goes further to ask what the pressure  will be at a depth of 100m, do i just plug in P=10(100)+100 to get 1100 kPa? And then if if asks what the depth is at pressure 725 kPa, do i just plug in 725=10d+100 and then solve to get 62.5?

Comment: That is correct! Nice job